# An example for two finitely generated and residually finite whose quotients are finite and Isomorphic, but themselves are not Isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm Trying to find an example for two non isomorphic,  finitely generated,    residually finite groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that there exists $N_1\unlhd G_1$,$N_2\unlhd G_2$ while $G_1/N_2 \cong G_2/N_2$ and $|[G_1:N_1]|=|[G_2:N_2]|<\infty$.

It's my understanding that residually finite is not the same as finitely presented. Thank's in advance to all responders.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think this question is only asking about one pair of finite quotients being the same, which is much simpler than the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any pair of non isomorphic f.g. residually finite groups $G_1$, $G_2$, and for $F$ finite, consider the groups $G_1\times F$, $G_2\times F$.

Here is something nontrivial: there exist non isomorphic finitely generated nilpotent groups (hence residually finite) with identical collections of finite quotients.

Comment: Do you mean that the normal subgroups in the example are:

$N_1=G_1\times F$ and $N_2=G_2\times F$.

And is the following example a proper one then:

$G_1:=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} _2$ and $G_2=\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \mathbb{Z} _2$, and the normal subgroups are $N_1:=\mathbb{Z} \times$ {$e$}, and $N_1:=\mathbb{Z}^2 \times$ {$e$}.

Comment: The normal subgroups are $G_1\times\{e\}$ and $G_2\times\{e\}$. Your example is correct.