# Example of $2$ non-isomorphic groups that have the same quotients

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm looking for an example of $2$ **non isomorphic** groups $G_1,G_2$  that are **finitely generated and presented** that have the same finite quotients (up to isomorphism) .

Thanks

Comment: nice question. I posted an answer to take a finite simple group cross a free group, but this is wrong.

Comment: Almost the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169904/an-example-for-two-finitely-generated-and-residually-finite-whose-quotients-are).

Answer (score 18):

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095028), I wrote down finite presentations from a paper by Baumslag and Solitar of two non-isomorphic groups that are each isomorphic to a quotient group of the other. So these two groups have exactly  the same quotient groups, not just the same finite quotient groups.

Answer (score 13):

There are [finitely presented infinite groups that have **no** nontrivial finite quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group).

You could take two of these.

There may be easier examples, though.

Answer (score 7):

There is a famous example of a non-residually finite one-relator group, 
$$\langle a, b \mid (ab)^{(ab)^a} = (ab)^2\rangle,$$
due to Baumslag, Miller and Troeger, which has the same finite quotients (the finite cyclic groups) as the infinite cyclic group.
It's a particular case of a more general result.  This appears in the following paper (which I just happened to have handy).

Gilbert Baumslag, Charles F. Miller III and Douglas Troeger, *Reflections on the residual finiteness of one-relator groups*,  Groups Geom. Dyn. 1 (2007), 209-219. [PDF](http://ms.unimelb.edu.au/~cfm/papers/paperpdfs/gbcmdt-ggd-2007-01-03-01.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The [Thompson groups $T < V$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) are nonisomorphic, finitely presented, infinite simple groups---so the only finite quotient they have in common is the trivial group.

[Cannon-Floyd-Parry's survey article](http://doi.org/10.5169/seals-87877) gives a presentation for $T$ with 3 generators and 2 relations, but maybe someone else has knocked it down to 2 generators since then.
The presentation they gave for $V$ was less friendly (4G, 14R).
Bleak and Quick give a 2-generator, 7-relator presentation for $V$ in [arXiv:1511.02123 [math.GR]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02123).

Answer (score -1):

Let $Z_k$ be the cyclic group of order $k$.

Consider, $A = Z_2 \times Z_2$ and $B = Z_4$.

These are not isomorphic to each other and the only non-trivial quotient they have is $Z_2$.

Comment: But $A$ does not have $B$ as a finite quotient and $B$ does not have $A$ so this does answer the question.